# Logcat displays Empty SMPTE 2094-40 data

Tags: android, logcat

When i connect my device to android studio logcat. It keeps displaying this message "Empty SMPTE 2094-40 data". Anyone knows where this is coming from or how to stop it?

Comment: I also met this situation and am searching for resolutions. If you have any ways to solve this, please post it.

Comment: This is driving me nuts, and makes inspecting the logcat a perpetual chore. It spams this error in bursts, for example whenever dragging any scrollable view. Pixel 6 userdebug build.

Comment: Hi Any one solve this issue. please if any one solve please add solution.

Comment: No still got no solution to this. Logcat is driving me insane with all the messages

Comment: I am also getting same error message in Logcat from last week.

Comment: Still getting these burst of logs on Android Studio  `Build #AI-222.4459.24.2221.9862592, built on March 31, 2023`

Comment: I have also encountered this issue. Recently, I upgraded from Gradle Plugin: 8.0.1 to 8.0.2

Answer (score 6):

In Android Studio, try to use this filter, package:mine -tag:gralloc4

ref:https://blog.csdn.net/qq_26914291/article/details/128837098

Comment: - format the filter in a code block
- add a sample screenshot on the exact place to enter the filter

Comment: I think the question was not how to use logcat filters but about the message itself. I have the same and I don't want just to ignore it as it was ranked as an error.

Answer (score 3):

From [Society of Motion Picture and Television Engineers](https://standards.globalspec.com/std/10044468/SMPTE%20ST%202094-40)

> SMPTE ST 2094-40

> This standard specifies the metadata for Color Volume Transform Application #4, Scene-based Color Volume Mapping. It is a specialization of the content-dependent transform metadata entries and processing blocks of the generalized color volume transform model defined in the SMPTE ST 2094-1 Core Components standard.

> Scene-based Color Volume Mapping consists of scene-based tone mapping and scene-based color saturation mapping processing blocks. These processing blocks make use of the peak luminance behaviors of the display used for mastering the image essence (i.e. the "mastering display") and the targeted system display as their ability to achieve peak luminance varies with the average brightness level of the pixels and the number of bright pixels within the scene. In addition to these adjustments that can be algorithmically determined from known display and content characteristics, Scene-based Color Volume Mapping also allows creatively approved adjustments.

From [Mozilla Wiki - Platform/GFX/Gralloc](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Platform/GFX/Gralloc)

> What is Gralloc?

> Gralloc is a type of shared memory that is also shared with the GPU. A Gralloc buffer can be written to directly by regular CPU code, but can also be used as an OpenGL texture. Gralloc is part of Android, and is also part of B2G. This is similar to the functionality provided by the EGL_lock_surface extension, but EGL_lock_surface is not widely supported on Android/B2G.  Gralloc buffers are represented by objects of the class android::GraphicBuffer. See ui/GraphicBuffer.h.

It looks like in the most recent updates, someone did not properly pass the color volume and scene color mapping data correctly, so the system is warning that it is operating based on an empty data set.

If you just need to get rid of the warnings:

From [Empty SMPTE 2094-40 data (note, this is a Chinese blog)](https://blog.csdn.net/qq_43962511/article/details/129729078?spm=1001.2101.3001.6650.3&utm_medium=distribute.pc_relevant.none-task-blog-2%7Edefault%7EYuanLiJiHua%7EPosition-3-129729078-blog-108923357.235%5Ev35%5Epc_relevant_anti_vip_base&depth_1-utm_source=distribute.pc_relevant.none-task-blog-2%7Edefault%7EYuanLiJiHua%7EPosition-3-129729078-blog-108923357.235%5Ev35%5Epc_relevant_anti_vip_base&utm_relevant_index=6):

You can type:

```
^(?!.(gralloc4)).$
```

Into your logcat filter box to get rid of the warnings.

Comment: Just wanted to add that in the new Logcat v2, you can use this with `-process=:gralloc4`, or alternatively only filter out the message with `-message=:"Empty SMPTE 2094-40 data"` and retain other messages from gralloc4 if needed.

Comment: thank you to you both. I finally can use my logcat without that message

Answer (score 1):

In new Logcat you can add gralloc4 in filter:

[image]

Comment: You might want to give more details on what to do exactly

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error. My previous flutter version was 3.3.9. I have upgraded my flutter to 3.10 and I don't see that error anymore.
So I'd suggest that you try the following commands:

```
flutter channel stable
flutter upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to your phone settings > Developer options > Debugging > set Logger buffer sizes to Off. You may get one issue when you install app again on device. If app not install then again set "Logger buffer size" to 256 KB and once app install again set it to off.

Answer (score 0):

It's depend on your OS, just upgrade or downgrade your emulator or device Android version or use logcat.
These filters helps you to fix it:

```
package:mine  -tag:gralloc4
```

or

```
package:<Your package name>  -tag:gralloc4
```

or

```
-message=: "Empty SMPTE 2094-40 data" package:<Your package name>
```